# Derivative with respect to the spacetime derivative of a field $\phi$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, tensor-calculus, notation, differentiation

I've encountered the following notation several times (for example, when discussing Noether's Theorem):
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}$$
And it's not immediately clear to me what this operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}$ refers to. Based on the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88935/derivative-with-respect-to-a-vector-is-a-gradient) and the structure of the covariant derivative, I'm guessing it's just a short-hand for the following operator:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}\equiv\pm(\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{\phi}},-\frac{\partial}{\partial(\nabla\phi)})$$
I.e.
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}\equiv\pm(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\phi}},-\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\nabla\phi)})$$
where the $\pm$ comes from your convention for the Minkowski metric.

This is just a guess. Can someone verify, perhaps with a source?

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing you - writing $\partial/\partial x$ means that you differentiate w.r.t. $x$. In this case, $x$ is $\partial_\mu \phi$, so you differentate the function $L(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi,t)$ with respect to that.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that you can always write a function as $L\{\phi,\partial_\mu \phi,t\}$. For example, how would you handle $L=\phi+\dot{\phi}$ (probably unphysical, but in principle), or $L=\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$?

Comment: _Covariant_ derivative in title (v4)? Did you mean _partial_ derivative?

Comment: No, its a derivative $\partial/\partial???$ with respect to a covariant derivative: $???=\partial_\mu \phi$

Comment: @ACuriousMind OP is confused because the outermost derivative doesn't have an index.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Nitpick: $\partial_\mu \phi$ does not refer to the covariant derivative, but rather the *partial* derivative wrt each coordinate. The covariant derivative would involve subtracting an additional term proportional to the Christoffel symbols. This, however, is not important for your question.

Comment: @aquirdturtle this strikes me as a misunderstanding of Lagrangians 101. There is this weird relation between $\phi$ and $\partial_i\phi$ in that technically the former determines the latter completely. But that relation only comes up in deriving the Euler Lagrange equations from the minimization of action. In all other cases the Lagrangian is *just a function* of some number of variables. Say, 1+1 dimensions, $L=L(a,b,c)$. We choose to minimize $\iint L(\phi,\partial_0\phi,\partial_1\phi)d^2x$.

Comment: (cont.) When I say $L=\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi-\phi^2$, I really mean $L(a,b,c)=b^2-c^2-a^2$. (plug in $a=\phi$, $b=\partial_0\phi$, $c=\partial_1 \phi$, $(1,-1)$ sign for the metric, and these are your regular partial derivatives from introductory calculus)

Comment: (cont. part 2) When I say $\partial L/\partial(\partial_0\phi)$, I really just mean I want to differentiate $L$ with respect to the second argument and then plug in $\phi$, $\partial_0\phi$, and $\partial_1\phi$ in its first, second, and third arguments.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I wouldn't be confused by the derivative with respect to a single derivative of the field, e.g. $\partial L/\partial(\partial_0\phi)$, I'm only confused when the covariant derivative: $\partial L/\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)$. As I said, the confusion is similar to the other question I linked to, which is what led me to my suggestion (d/dt,-del) of another way of writing the operator.

Comment: @aquirdturtle The covariant derivative of a scalar is a partial derivative. You can treat $\mu$ as a given but fixed integer representing the component of a value in some coordinate basis. $\partial_i \phi=\partial\phi/\partial x^i$ is a plain old partial derivative, and $0\le i \le 3$ is a plain old integer. If you understand for a "single derivative", then with my comments it should be clear how to find $\partial L/(\partial(\partial_\mu \phi))$ for any fixed $\mu$. Then you can put all of the components into a vector and go back to using whatever abstract index notation you choose to use.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy This interpretation seems contradictory to the notion of four-vectors & tensors as representable as matrices. Specifically, If I view $x_\nu$ as the $\nu$th element of the x four-vector, then $x_\nu g_{\mu\nu}$, when coupled with Einstein notation, is perfectly well-defined. However if I view $x^\nu$ as the four-vector itself, and representable as $[x_0;x_1;x_2;x_3]$, then $x_\nu g_{\nu\mu}$ is not well-defined as it's a 4x1 X 4x4 multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

In field theory usually you have a Lagrangian density function of fields and first derivative of fields or
$$\mathscr{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi).$$ It is well know that higher derivative of field than first are in some way problematic (Hamiltonian not bounded from below). Field equations follow from Euler-Lagrange equations in which you treat $\phi$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$ as independent variables. The same happen in Classical Mechanic where your Lagrangian is a function of two variables $q$ and $\dot{q}$. So if you are familiar with $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}$$ you should become familiar with the field theoretic version.

Comment: I don't think I agree, there is always concatenation involved inside the Lagrangian or else it would be $L_\mu=L_\mu(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)$. My confusion relates to how to deal with this, and how to formally deal with terms like $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$. It also seems like I should be able to construct terms in lagrangians which are clearly not functions of only $\phi$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$, so you're first statement seems strange to me.

Comment: Please show us such lagrangian function of other than fields and first derivative of fields. Also, lagrangian is a scalar so no free index attached to it..

Comment: I'm thinking of things like $L = \nabla^2\phi$ as a really simple example. It seems plausible that such extraneous terms are always completely unphysical and so I just should worry about it. For simple cases such as this one above it at least makes the lagrangian not lorentz invariant.

Comment: Yes I agree that the lagrangian should have no free indexes attached to it, your notation of $L=L(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)$ just struck me as weird. Maybe it shouldn't have.

Comment: @aquirdturtle: $\nabla^2 \phi$ is indeed not a function of the field and its first derivatives, though you can integrate it by parts to get $\nabla\phi\cdot \nabla\phi$. And $L(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi)$ is short for $L(\phi, \partial_0 \phi, \dots, \partial_4 \phi)$.

Answer (score 0):

This article is a useful start.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

So throughout the discussions with the kind folks here I think that I've sorted out my confusion, although there wasn't any particular answer that did it. Here I'll analyze my confusion over this notation in case anyone comes to this thread with similar confusions.

The most straightforward answer (IMO) to the question "how do I interpret $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}$?" is to interpret as four distinct operators. I.e.
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)} = [\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_1\phi)}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_2\phi)}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_3\phi)}]
$$

This is essentially what I suggested in my question, but it wasn't obvious to me that it was necessarily correct. The reason I didn't immediately jump to this conclusion when I saw this is that we often (usually?) talk about four-vectors (using the $\mu$ notation $\partial_\mu$) as composite objects, not as elements of composite objects. For example, whether it's strictly speaking correct or not, I have often seen people refer to $\partial_\mu$ as the covariant derivative, **not** the $\mu$th element of the covariant derivative. Similarly, I see the notation $x_\mu = [t,x,y,z]$ and *not* $x_\mu = [t,x,y,z]_\mu$, which would more strongly reinforce the idea that $x_\mu$ is referring to a single but arbitrary element of the collection $[t,x,y,z]$. All of these things encouraged me to think of the term $x_\mu$ as the entire collection, not as an arbitrary element of said collection. In fact these seem like incompatible interpretations to me. For example, if I interpret these objects as arbitrary elements of said collections, then the term $x_\nu g_{\nu\mu}$ (which I have directly seen in work before) is perfectly well-defined, while if I interpret $x_\nu$ as a vector and $g_{\nu\mu}$ as a matrix, then it clearly isn't.

However there does seem to be another consistent way to work with these derivatives which **does** abstract out the $\partial_\mu\phi$ as an entire object, like $x$, for the derivative to be taken with respect to. Sean Carroll briefly describes how to work with this in his book "Spacetime and Geometry". It seems a bit tricky though. He gives the guidelines that, to be careful, to make sure that the "derivitee" is expressed with tensors with subscripts in the same places as the parameter the derivative is with respect to, and to use different subscripts for the two as well. For example,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\xi \phi)} (\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi) = \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\xi\phi)} (\frac{1}{2}g^{\nu\mu}\partial_\nu\phi\partial_\mu\phi) = \frac{1}{2}g^{\nu\mu}(\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\xi\phi)} (\partial_\nu\phi)\partial_\mu\phi + \partial_\nu\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\xi\phi)} (\partial_\mu\phi))
= \frac{1}{2}g^{\nu\mu}(\delta^\xi_\nu\partial_\mu\phi + \partial_\nu\phi \delta^\xi_\mu) = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi = \partial^\nu\phi
$$

It seems to me like there might be cases in which this sort of approach breaks down, such as if I ever had a Lagrangian (or other thing that I wanted to take the derivative of) like $L = \nabla^2\phi$. Maybe dealing with that's trivial and I just don't see it, but at this point I'd return to my previous interpretation, as while less compact, it seems a little more trustworthy.

Sorry if I seem a bit thick as I try to grapple with this notation but I've had an unusually hard time working with it and this result was not obvious to me. Let me know if I've still got something wrong in here. Thanks all.