# Derivative with respect to vector of a function depending on vectors

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential, vectors, differentiation

I've been trying to understand this concept for hours without any success. I found similar questions on this forum ([Derivative with respect to a vector is a gradient?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88935/derivative-with-respect-to-a-vector-is-a-gradient?newreg=076762f4a1fc4b9e84a5e8d5e0755143)) but I still don't understand.

Let's consider a multiple particle system with $n$ particles. I'm running multiple times into the notation
$$\vec{F_k}=- \frac{\partial}{\partial  \vec{x_k}} V(\vec{x_1},\vec{x_2},..., \vec{x_n})$$
where $F_k$ denotes the resulting force acting on the particle $k$.

I assume the right hand side is an $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector because the left hand side is.

I came up with one example:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x_1, ... ,x_n)=3x_1+{x_2}^2x_4-5x_3+...+x_n$
Then (because the variables are real) I know:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x_1,...x_n)=3 \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f(x_1,...x_n)=2x_2x_4 \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}f(x_1,...x_n)=-5$$
Now I guess one could define $\vec{a}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{a}}f(x_1,...x_n)=(3,2x_2x_4,-5)^T$

Even if this is correct, I'm struggling to apply this idea to the potential $V$ above because the variables there aren't scalars. What if for example $V(\vec{x_1},\vec{x_2},..., \vec{x_n})=\vec{x_1}^3$ ? Raising a vector to the 3rd power doesn't make any sense to me. Should I think of V as a function $V(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13},...,x_{n1},x_{n2},x_{n3}): \mathbb{R}^{3n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

I'm sorry about the long question but I hope to have at least clarified my problems and possibly helped you to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about newtonian mechanics, then $\mathbf{F} = - \nabla V$. I'm not sure why you're indexing $\mathbf{F}$, either it's a vector $\mathbf{F}$ or you're referring to the components $F_k$. The components are then $F_k = \left[-\nabla V \right]_k = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}$.
In general if you have a scalar function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ then you can define the directional derivative just like a normal derivative as
\begin{align*}
\partial_{\mathbf{v}} f\big|_{\mathbf{x_0}}& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}_0 + h \mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0)}{h} \\
&= \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla f
\end{align*}
When you have multiple variables then the slope of the function can obviously be different if you're "walking" in different directions.

The notation $\mathbf{x}^3$ is usually meant as repeated scalar products, therefore $\mathbf{x}^2 = ||\mathbf{x}||^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is actually just a scalar but $\mathbf{x}^3 = \mathbf{x}^2 \mathbf{x} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ is then a vector. Taking the derivative along $\mathbf{v} = (1, 0, 1)$ would then be
\begin{align*}
\partial_{\mathbf{v}} \mathbf{x}^3 &= \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{x}^3 \\
&= \mathbf{v} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 \\ x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= 1(3x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 0 (x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2) + 1 (x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2) 
\end{align*}

To illustrate it with multiple particles, let's look at the Kepler problem and ignore the constants for a second, then $V(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2) = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|} = \left((x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 + (z_1 + z_2)^2 \right)^{-1/2} = V(x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2)$.
The force on the first particle is then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{F}_1(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2) &= - \frac{\partial V}{\partial \mathbf{r}_1} = -\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_1} V = (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) \nabla V \\
&= - \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1} V \\ \partial_{y_1} V \\ \partial_{z_1} V \end{pmatrix} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{((x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 + (z_1 - z_2)^2 )^{3/2}} \begin{pmatrix} 2(x_1 - x_2) \\ 2(y_1 - y_2) \\ 2(z_1 - z_2) \end{pmatrix} \\
&= - \frac{\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|^3}
\end{align*}
Note that $(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ points along $\mathbf{r}_1$. The last line is just Newton's law of gravity $\mathbf{F}_G = \frac{1}{r^2}\mathbf{e}_r$. So your comment is correct.

Comment: I think I'm getting there. I consider a multiple particle system in newtonian mechanics, $F_k$ denotes the resulting force on particle $k$. As 2piOmega suggested, is it correct to think of $V=V(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13},...,x_{n3})$ as a function $V:\mathbb{R}^{3n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?. If yes, is it then correct to say $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x_k}}V=\frac{\partial}{\partial (x_{k1},x_{k2},x_{k3})^T}V=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k1}}V,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k2}}V,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k3}}V)^T $ ? I think here is where my main problem lies.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Your example was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the notation $ \frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{x_k}}} $ stand for the gradient $ \vec{\nabla} $. The gradient operator act on scalar funtion like $V$ and gives a vector :
$$\vec{\nabla} V= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_1}}V\\ 
\dots \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_n}}V
\end{pmatrix}  $$
Here you describe $V$ as a function of multiple vectors but i think is like you use one vector that contains all the $\vec{x_i}$ coefficients $V(x_{11},x_{12},...,x_{n3})$.
You give the example of $V=\vec{x_1}^3$ in this case $V$ depend only on $x_1$ and either $V=x_1^2 \vec{x_1}$ and $V$ is a vector or $V=|\vec{x_1}|^3$ and this is a scalar.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression appears to be referring to the scalar potential, V, (of an object) the value of which depends on its position in a multi-space specified by coordinates: x, y, z, and perhaps more. Then the force on the object depends on the gradient of the potential which is found by summing the partial derivatives with respect to each dimension.  Though I have not seen a formal definition of the operation of dividing a scalar by a vector, this expression seems to imply that would be done in terms of components.